# Qt - don't destroy thread after slot is finished

Tags: qt, qt4, qthread

Is there a way to prevent a thread created inside a slot to be destroyed, after the slot is finished ?

```
    <widget.cpp>

    ...
    void Widget::<slot_name>()
    {
        ...
        ThreadTask Watcher; //ThreadTask is defined in header file
        QThread WatcherThread;
        Watcher.moveToThread(&WatcherThread);
        QObject::connect ...
        WatcherThread.start();
        ...
    }
```

I know I could declare the thread outside the slot and only start it from it, but the thing is, I would like to create another thread if the same slot is triggered again.

Comment: You seem to not know some C++ basics about heap and stack allocation. Read some good C++ books as you will need at least basics of C++ to use Qt

Comment: That's true, I've been doing a lot of scripting in the past and only recently moved to OOP, but I keep thinking sequentially, as in scripts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [dynamic allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) :

```
QThread* WatcherThread = new Qthread();
```

Notice that you **must** delete it when the thread's execution has finished in order to avoid a memory leak.

Qt could automatically delete the thread when it finishes if you use the following code:

```
connect(WatcherThread , SIGNAL(finished()),
    WatcherThread , SLOT(deleteLater()));
```

Comment: And what about ThreadTask? It also should by allocated on the heap

Comment: You are right, i thought it was obvious to do the same for ThreadTask